# Error: more than one config file specified in protractor

Tags: visual-studio, protractor

I'm trying to configure visual studio to run protractor tests using this tutorial http://goo.gl/lsjMEi

I've included node_modules\protractor\lib\cli.js into my project and set is as node.js startup file, and in my project propreties, i've defined my conf.js as script agruments. When i run my project, i get this message:

> Error: more than one config file specified

This is my project structure:

[image: Structure]

Comment: Is there a log message where you can see the command that is being executed to run node?

Comment: Consider answering your own question so it doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I've set in project properties the whole path of conf.js insted just **conf.js**.

Comment: how to do this exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to make sure you add '--' before any parameters.

```
protractor config param="foo" //This will fail with 'more than one config file'


protractor config --param="foo" //This will succeed
```